# Django Models : Get elements considering their presence as a foreign key in another table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a hard time explaining exactly what I'm trying to do with Django Models, but I managed to write down the MySQL queries.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class OwnedItem(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    isWorking = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

MySQL version: http://pastebin.com/kyiMCJfm

Get all items owned by John that are working:

```
SELECT i.*, o.Owner, o.isWorking FROM Item as i JOIN OwnedItem AS o WHERE o.Item = i.Id AND o.Owner = 'john' AND o.isWorking=1 GROUP BY i.id
```

Get all items John doesn't own or that are not working:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM OwnedItem WHERE owner='john' AND isWorking=1)
```

How can I write those queries using the Django models syntax?

Comment: Will you please give your models defination?

Comment: I already gave the tables information, but here is an SQL implementation if you want to try it: http://pastebin.com/kyiMCJfm It's easy to convert it in Django Models

Comment: If you need solution in `models syntax` then model definitions will help.

Comment: I edited my post with the django models version :)

Comment: And I think you have answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st

```
Item.objects.filter(itemowned__owner__username__iexact="john", 
                   itemowned__isworking=True)
```

For 2nd, you need to use `Q` objects

```
Item.objects.exclude(Q(itemowned__owner__username__iexact="john") |
                    Q(itemowned__isworking=True))
```